# Construção de cronômetro

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2017

Estou construindo um cronômetro utilizando *WPF*. Quando eu realizei alguns testes, percebi que o cronômetro em *WPF* fica atrasado em relação ao cronômetro do meu *iPhone*. A diferença começa a aparecer a partir de 8 segundos de decorrido o inicio da cronometragem.

Abaixo eu disponibilizei o código do método *Timer_tick*.

```
private void Timer_Tick(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
        //lblTime.Content = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
        //lblTime.Content = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss:fff");

        //milliseconds++;
        //if (milliseconds >= 1000) {
        //    sec++;
        //    milliseconds = 0;
        //}
        //if (sec == 60) {
        //    min++;
        //    sec = 0;
        //}
        //lblTime.Content = string.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:D3}",min,sec,milliseconds);


        milliseconds += 15.560;

        if (milliseconds >= 1000) {
            milliseconds = 0;
            sec++;

            if (sec >= 60) {
                sec = 0;
                min++;
            }
        }

        lblTime.Content = min.ToString("00") + ":" + sec.ToString("00") + ":" +
            milliseconds.ToString("000").Substring(0,3);

        //lblTime.Content = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:000}", timer.Interval.Minutes, timer.Interval.Seconds, timer.Interval.Milliseconds);
    }
```

Abaixo o código do botão 'Start':

```
        private void Start(object sender,EventArgs e)
        {
          timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1);
          timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
          timer.Start();
        }
```

Este é o código da classe inteira:

```
public partial class MainWindow :Window
    {
        DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();

        int min = 0, sec = 0;
        double milliseconds = 0;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Timer_Tick(object sender,EventArgs e)
        {
            //lblTime.Content = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
            //lblTime.Content = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss:fff");

            //milliseconds++;
            //if (milliseconds >= 1000) {
            //    sec++;
            //    milliseconds = 0;
            //}
            //if (sec == 60) {
            //    min++;
            //    sec = 0;
            //}
            //lblTime.Content = string.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:D3}",min,sec,milliseconds);


            milliseconds += 15.560;

            if (milliseconds >= 1000) {
                milliseconds = 0;
                sec++;

                if (sec >= 60) {
                    sec = 0;
                    min++;
                }
            }

            lblTime.Content = min.ToString("00") + ":" + sec.ToString("00") + ":" +
                milliseconds.ToString("000").Substring(0,3);

            //lblTime.Content = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:000}", timer.Interval.Minutes, timer.Interval.Seconds, timer.Interval.Milliseconds);
        }

        private void Start(object sender,EventArgs e)
        {
            timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1);
            timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
            timer.Start();
        }
    }
```

Já tentei vários tutoriais mas ainda não consegui um cronômetro onde não houvesse tanta diferença de tempo. Não sei se é devido ao desempenho do *WPF* ser considerado menor do que o do *WinForm*.

Eu já havia feito esse mesmo cronômetro em *WinForm* e a diferença temporal era imperceptível.

Há um outro problema, o cronômetro não está exibindo no formato *MM:SS:MMM*. Não sei se o *.substring* que estou aplicando na atualização do *label* está errado ou se o *interval* está errado.

Comment: Qual o interval definido no timer ? 1ms ?

Comment: Por que não usar um TimeSpan ao invés de criar um?

Comment: cara.. sempre vai atrasar.. voce quer fazer o tick de 1 em 1 ms e o tempo de processamento é maior que esse 1 ms entre os ticks.. portanto  vai sempre existir essa diferença..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use o **StopWatch** no C#

```
    Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

    stopwatch.Start();
    for (; ;)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(stopwatch.Elapsed);
    }
```

No WPF você pode fazer assim, mas dá pra melhorar bastante esse código:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
    private Timer timer;
    private DispatcherTimer dispatcherTimer;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        stopwatch.Stop();
        dispatcherTimer.Stop();
    }

    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        stopwatch.Start();
        dispatcherTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
        dispatcherTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(dispatcherTimer_Tick);
        dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 10);
        dispatcherTimer.Start();
    }

    private void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblTimer.Content = stopwatch.Elapsed;
    }
}
```

Comment: Obrigado. Este modelo que você me passou funcionou bem.

Answer (score 0):

Este foi o resultado. Adaptado para a minha necessidade. Funcionou muito bem.
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Windows.Threading;

namespace StopWatchWPF
{
    public partial class MainWindow :Window
    {
        DispatcherTimer dt = new DispatcherTimer();
        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        string currentTime = string.Empty;

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        dt.Tick += new EventHandler(dt_Tick);
        dt.Interval = new TimeSpan(0,0,0,0,1);
    }

    private void dt_Tick(object sender,EventArgs e)
    {
        if (sw.IsRunning) {
            TimeSpan ts = sw.Elapsed;
            currentTime = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:000}",
            ts.Minutes,ts.Seconds,ts.Milliseconds);
            lblTime.Content = currentTime;
        }
    }

    private void Start(object sender,RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        sw.Start();
        dt.Start();
    }

    private void Stop(object sender,RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (sw.IsRunning) {
            sw.Stop();
        }
        elapsedtimeitem.Items.Add(currentTime);
    }

    private void Lap(object sender,RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        elapsedtimeitem.Items.Add(currentTime);
        sw.Reset();
        lblTime.Content= "00:00:000";
        sw.Start();
    }
}
```

}